# python 2.7 script running two while loops in parallel indefinitely

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, while-loop

I am trying to execute some code on a Beaglebone Black running ubuntu.  The script has two primary functions:
1: count digital pulse
2: store the counted pulses in mySQL every 10s or so

These two functions need to run idefinitely.

My question is how to do get these two functions to run in parallel?  Here is my latest code revision that doesn't work so you can see what I am attempting to do.  Any help much appreciated -- as I new to python.

Thank you in advance!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
import MySQLdb
import time
import thread
from threading import Thread


now = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
total1 = 0
total2 = 0


def insertDB_10sec(now, total1, total2):
    while True:
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(host ="localhost", 
            user="root", 
            passwd="password", 
            db="dbname")
        cursor= conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",  (now, total1, total2))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        print "DB Entry Made"
        time.sleep(10)

def countPulse():
    now = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    GPIO.setup("P8_12", GPIO.IN)
    total1 = 0
   total2 = 0
   while True:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge("P8_12", GPIO.RISING)
    GPIO.wait_for_edge("P8_12", GPIO.FALLING)
    now = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print now
    total1 +=1
    print total1
    return now, total1, total2 

t1 = Thread(target = countPulse)
t2 = Thread(target = insertDB_10sec(now, total1, total2))

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Comment: What does it do when you run it?

Comment: With the above code it I get one print out 'DB Entry Made' then it waits 10s and give me a mySQL error -- duplicate entry. For some reason the countPulse thread is not kicking off and returning new values for the insertDB thread.  Seams odd to me beacuse I am starting the countPulse thread first?

Comment: Do you want to store all pulses, or just whatever the pulse happens to be at each 10 second interval?

Comment: Both ways.  I have storing all pulses figured out doing in one loop i think.   But I'd really like the option of storing pulses accumulated over the 10s interval.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect problem for a `Queue`!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
import MySQLdb
import time
import thread
import Queue
from threading import Thread


now = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
total1 = 0
total2 = 0

pulse_objects = Queue.Queue()


def insertDB_10sec(pulse_objects):
    while True:
        now,total1,total2 = pulse_objects.get()
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(host ="localhost", 
            user="root", 
            passwd="password", 
            db="dbname")
        cursor= conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",  (now, total1, total2))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        print "DB Entry Made"
        time.sleep(10)

def countPulse(pulse_objects):
    now = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    GPIO.setup("P8_12", GPIO.IN)
    total1 = 0
    total2 = 0
    while True:
        GPIO.wait_for_edge("P8_12", GPIO.RISING)
        GPIO.wait_for_edge("P8_12", GPIO.FALLING)
        now = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print now
        total1 +=1
        print total1
        pulse_objects.put( (now, total1, total2) )

t1 = Thread(target = countPulse, args = (pulse_objects,))
t2 = Thread(target = insertDB_10sec, args = (pulse_objects,))

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Comment: This has to run in python 2.7.  Isn't queue in 3.3?

Comment: You may want to tag it as such. `queue` exists in 2.7, it's just `Queue` there :) I'll update my answer

Comment: Getting errors:   TypeError: countPulse() argument after * must be a sequence, not instance
 
'TypeError: insertDB_10sec() argument after * must be a sequence, not instance' @adsmith

Comment: did you put `args = pulse_objects` or `args = (pulse_objects)` ? The latter should work, as it's passing a tuple containing one item, "pulse_objects"

Comment: 'args = (pulse_objects)'.  Just tried the former and getting same error with either. @adsmith

Comment: Oh, sorry, the problem was an obvious syntax error on my part. `args = (pulse_objects,)` will work, with the trailing comma. Otherwise it's just handing it an object which it assumes is a sequence. It's not a tuple without a comma. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: do the defs need pulse_objects as an arg in the definition? @adsmith

Comment: @user2133624 They DO have them, what are you talking about >.> <.< (apparently I forgot how to program sometime between 10pm last night when I wrapped up my last project and this morning when I've made 20 of the most novice syntax errors on your answer)

Comment: Hmmm that code is working but now I seam to be incrementing total1 when there are no pulses coming through?  WHen there are no pulses the countPulse function is not outputing the print statements so I can but somehow total1 is still incrementing...?? @adsmith

Comment: @user2133624 there was some funky indentation in your original code that made its way into mine. Try now. It shouldn't be incrementing if it's not printing -- there's no line of code that would do that in my source.

Comment: ah i see that the total1 is not being correctly update into the pulse_object.put statement. So I only see +1 for each entry into the DB while the print total1 statement in the countPulse loops shows the correct number?

Comment: Not sure, to be honest. Try removing your two global `total1` and `total2` vars since we're not using them. The namespaces shouldn't be getting confused, but it's possible I missed something.

Comment: What about needing pulse_objects in the insert statement instead of (now, total1, total2)? @adsmith

Comment: Wouldn't make sense. `pulse_objects.get()` returns the FIFO object (which should be a tuple `(now, total1, total2)` and unpacks it. Something else is going wrong.

Comment: Ya.  I added a print below the now,total1, total2 = pulse_objects.get() and i see that the value it prints does not match the total1 being printed in the countPulses function. funky. @adsmith

Comment: its the time.sleep(10) line.  its taking the pulse_objects value form 10s before or something weird like that. @adsmith

Comment: Can't be. `Queue.get()` will pause the thread at that line until there's something in the Queue, so `t1` will start, `t2` will start then pause as its first line is waiting on a `Queue.get`. `t1` will get a pulse, do `Queue.put()` to put it in the Queue, then `t2` will take off with it, and wait 10s to look for another one.

Comment: If you're trying to write a pulse every 10 seconds, then do `time.sleep(10)` on your producer thread, not your consumer thread. e.g. at the bottom of `countPulse` have it wait 10 seconds before looking for another heartbeat. `insertDB_10sec` will wait until there's something in the queue to write to your DB, so if you only put something in the queue every 10s, that should do it right?

Comment: i like the idea but think if i sleep the `countPulse` thread it will miss incrementing the total1?  Ah wait!  maybe that is it. as it stand s the `countPulse` thread keeps incrementing the total1 but does `pulse_objects` get updated only after it has been used by the consumer?  That is, we want pulse_objects to update the total1 value after counting pulses for 10s! @adsmith

Comment: Currently, `countPulse` will grab all the heartbeats it can (it runs constantly with no throttle) and increase `total1` each time. `insertDB_10sec` will only grab a heartbeat once every 10 seconds, so your Queue will get VERY full VERY fast. If you want to continue grabbing heartbeats as fast as you can, but only increment `total1` once every 10s, you'll need to use `datetime.timedelta` to keep track of time change without sleeping your function.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need two threads? Move the insert to `countPulse`. That being said:

You should not call `insertDB_10sec` here:

```
t2 = Thread(target = insertDB_10sec(now, total1, total2))
```

Provide the arguments as actual arguments:

```
t2 = Thread(target = insertDB_10sec, args=(now, total1, total2))
```

This will still not do what you intend, because `now, total1, total2` are local variables in `countPulse`. Instead declare them as global:

```
global now
global total1
global total2
```

The same holds for the other thread, because you pass the variables there at start. Remove the arguments to `insertDB_10sec` all together.

Why would you want to store a new database entry every ten seconds regardless of what the other thread does? Your comment suggests that the field for `now` is unique. Therefore you should first check whether `now` changed before you try to insert again. Or replace `INSERT INTO` with `REPLACE INTO`.

Comment: Yes now is unique. So you are suggesting that i just run one thread and store every new pulse count in the table?  And if now already exists then replace it with the new value (as I can count more than one pulse in a second)?

Comment: @user2133624 Yes, if you simply move the insert to the point where you have a new pulse to store, then you neither have to worry about threading nor duplicates.

Comment: This will work, but destroy all the fun. :-/ ( :-)  )